# Currency Conversion - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I have a question about what the best way is to convert currency at a page.

At the moment I have a lot of input fields with a certain currency. When the user clicks on the currency conversion button a modal popup will open. When the user has made his choice he can click save and the modal will close automatically. What happened is that the currency and currency rate has been saved to the database.

What is the best way to update the values clientside and inside the database and ofcourse what is the best way performance wise?

EDIT:

currencyFilter:

```
export function FormatCurrencyFilter(currencyService: ICurrencyService, userProfileService: IUserProfileService) {
    return (input: any, format: string) => {
        if (input === undefined || input === null || isNaN(input))
            return input;

        format = format || '0,0.00 $';

        let rate = currencyService.currentCurrencyRate;
        input = input * rate;

        let n: Numeral = numeral(input);
        let language: any = numeral['languageData']();
        language.currency.symbol = currencyService.currentCurrency.code;
        language.delimiters.thousands = userProfileService.impersonatedProfile.formatNumberThousand;
        language.delimiters.decimal = userProfileService.impersonatedProfile.formatNumberDecimal;

        return n.format(format);
    };
```

HTML Tag:

```
<p class="form-control" editable-text="peril.value" editable-currency>{{::peril.value | formatCurrency}}</p>
```

Thanks, Brent

Answer (score 0):

Use [angular currency filters](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_currency.asp) for this.

Comment: I am using a custom currency filter. When I update the value inside the filter it will only update clientside and not on the model.

Comment: Can you add the custom currency filter in your question?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a POST request to send some data to the database. On the server side, process the request, and then send a response with the updated data. You should use a promise once the modal is closed to ensure that the request is complete before the client side application continues execution. So in summary

1. User opens modal, selects the currency and confirms.
2. Client sends POST to server with some data. Client waits for
       response
3. Server process the data, saves to the database
4. Server sends a response to the client
5. Client receives response, continues code execution